# Live Background in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

In which way do I have to investigate if I want to bring some life into the background of my Windows Store App? I thought about something very simple for the beginning like moving the sun depending on time or generating bubbles every 10 seconds or moving a plane in different heights for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`Background` property is of type `Brush` - you can try some [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452703.aspx) on it.

The other solution would be to set `MediaElement` as the background of your app:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MediaElement Source="sampleVideo.wmv" IsLooping="True" />
        <Grid>

        </Grid> 
 </Grid>
```